# how to update layout xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am creating a custom theme for Magento 2. I need to customize the layout existing in app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[CustomTheme]/Magento_Theme/layout] whose name is default.xml.

I have changed it by adding and changing some things, however, changes are not taken into account. I always see the original layout.

I have disabled cache, however, just in case, I have flushed it but it was unsuccessful.

How can I reload the layout? maybe it was stored in database, but, how can I refresh it?

Comment: Do you need to overight xml file?

Comment: No.... I have done a new theme with its own layout.xml file. That theme inherits Luma theme but that is other fact. The problem is that the custom layout.xml file was taken into account the first time, however, I have changed it, but I cannot get it to be updated by Magento.